# Conexão SQL Server no laravel

Tags: sql-server, laravel-5, sql-server-2012, wampserver

Galera, estou com o seguinte erro:
sqlstate 08001:[Microsoft][odbc driver 11 for sql server] provedor tcp: nenhuma conexão pode ser feita por que a maquina de destino as recusou ativamente.

estou utilizando um banco criado na minha própria maquina, esta com os drivers ODBC, firewall desabilitado, entretanto utilizo o wamp para executar. 
Alguem tem ideia de como resolver?

Valeus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consegui resolver da seguinte maneira:

Abra o SQL Server Configuration Manager. Vá em SQL Server Network Configuration -> TCP/IP. Troque para Enable e na abla IPAddresses, IPAll deixe TCP Dynamic ports em branco e TCP Port 1433. Lembrando que terá que configurar no Laravel corretamente.